# How to get existing domain name on route53 by terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to make a record in the existing dns name on route53. How can I do this in terraform?

Comment: Did you take a look at Terraform docs?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add DNS records to existing zones by using the "aws_route53_record"

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  name    = "www.example.com"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [aws_eip.lb.public_ip]
}
```

official reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record